# Enable debug logging firebase analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to enable debug logging for Firebase analytics in Android Studio. I have tried following the instructions found here and still don't see the logs I expect: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#log_events

[image]

When I run the commands described in the link (and shown above) in the terminal within Android Studio this is the output I see:

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of main
05-19 20:14:12.794 I/FA      ( 3083): App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
05-19 20:14:12.794 I/FA      ( 3083): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
```

and this is what is shown in the Android Monitor tab in logcat:

```
05-19 20:14:12.794 3083-3083/com.nick.app I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
05-19 20:14:12.794 3083-3083/com.nick.app I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
```

What I expect to see is an indication the various "events" I have logged are logged correctly. I have seen them in the firebase developer console which leads me to believe I have implemented them properly, I would just like a quicker way to know for testing purposes.

What steps need to be taken to properly view the firebase analytics debug logs?

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you run the `adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE` and then you restart the app. Enabling logs only works for future logs. If you have more then one device or emulator attached to the computer you might need to tell adb which one you are setting the property for. You can read the current adb properties with `adb shell getprop`. You should see `log.tag.FA` property set to `VERBOSE`. Once you set the `log.tag.FA` property it will persist until you restart the device so you only need to do that once after the device reboots.

Comment: I was able to get this to work once following your advices, but I cannot repeat it. When `adb shell getprop` is run, what should the output be to indicate the `log.tag.FA` property is `VERBOSE`? When that command is run I get a huge list in the format [XX.YY.ZZ]:[VALUE]

Comment: adb shell getprop prints all Android system properties. You can either filter the option or give getprop property name and it will return only the property value:

adb shell getprop log.tag.FA

should return VERBOSE.

http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-getprop

Answer (score 6):

Please try to do this after input "adb root".

Comment: this can be added as comment, once enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

Something that are maybe obvious to most people, but took me awhile to learn:

- this does require root, `adb root` did not work on my physical device.
- an emulator will give you root, but...
- be sure you create your emulator with an image that contains Google API's, so that it will have play services.

Comment: Which commant exactly requires root? Everything works for me without rooted device

Comment: This was quite awhile ago so I don't remember much of the details. I think what I found was that it was not enough to enable debugging on a device. That to get logging from a physical device, you needed root access on the device. It's possible I was doing something wrong. It's also possible that it is different in different android versions. But I do remember that I ended up wishing I had a developer device or a device I could safely root.