# Android & Firebase Analytics not register data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Hi I create an Android project add Firebase Analytics and use the guides to complete the process (the project compile and works). 
Now I use debug view and crash reporting works fine in console firebase analytics.
The problem is that console no registry some data (events or view report). I wait over 3 days and not show events or view report. But registre crash and debug view works with events.

[image: Images Firebase]

Comment: Did you create a project, delete and reuse the same bundle/package ID? If so, it is probably a known bug and you should contact Firebase support.

Comment: I create bundle/package ID for first time (with company name). Thanks for comment!!

Comment: What events are missing?  Are they custom events or automatic events?

Comment: @DanMorenus All events are missing. Only works debug view and crash reporting.

Comment: Can you run the app on a test device, [enable verbose logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336103/enable-debug-logging-firebase-analytics),
and post the output?  Wait for the events to upload; you should see a line that starts, "Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data:". Please include the log of the uploaded event bundle.  For faster uploading make sure [debug mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) is enabled on that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem, its for rename packages of project. 
Its strange problem because works in debug console (I think because I no change the configuration id), But doesn´t work fine at all because the package of classes are not the same than you register. Now I rename again all packages and works fine.