# Enable Debug mode on your development device for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have some user properties/tags that I want to test in real-time in the firebase console. I have have all the piping set up correctly as I do see tags from builds uploaded hours later.

I have read that the command `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>` should take care of that but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Steps I have taken:

1. Ran build via Android Studio
2. Opened terminal in Android Studio and ran `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.x.y.android.qa.debug` (Where x and y are my app identifiers, qa is the flavor and debug for debug build)

I still see no devices available in my Firebase DebugView dashboard.

Am I missing a step? Do I need to build and deploy app from the command line?

Thanks,
Otterman

Comment: can you check whether the Google App ID of your app is the same with the on in Firebase Dashboard?

Answer (score 5):

What you've done should be perfectly enough. Simple build and deploy through Android Studio will do.

It might be helpful to enable Firebase logs (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37351278)):

`adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE`

Then in Android Monitor, filter logs for Firebase

Also make sure your device has Internet access. I know it's silly, but it was my case ;)